# Add column of filename to hundreds of files bash

Tags: awk, sed

I have hundreds of genome wide association study files of ~10million rows. For `file1.txt`:

```
SNP BP B   SE   P
123 12 0.1 0.01 0.1
...
```

I want to add a column to the end of each file that contains only the name of that file so that the end result for `file1.txt` is:

```
SNP BP B   SE   P   name
123 12 0.1 0.01 0.1 file1.txt
...
```

I want to do this for hundreds of files. Currently I can add a column using:

```
for file in *.txt; do awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}{print $0, FILENAME}' $file; done
```

This will print the entire file but it will not overwrite the existing file. I just want to add a column to already existing data frames. Any advice much appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
tmp=$(mktemp) || { ret="$?"; printf 'Failed to create temp file\n'; exit "$ret"; }
for file in *.txt; do
    awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} {print $0, (FNR>1 ? FILENAME : "name")}' "$file" > "$tmp" &&
    mv -- "$tmp" "$file" || exit
done
```

If you have GNU awk and don't have so many files you exceed the shell arguments limit you can instead use just a call to awk with no surrounding shell loop and explicitly created temp file (it'll still use a temp file behind the scenes, just like all tools that have an option for "inplace" editing):

```
awk -i inplace 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} {print $0, (FNR>1 ? FILENAME : "name")}' *.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If `ed` is available/acceptable.

```
for file in *.txt; do
  printf '%s\n' "2,\$s|^\(.*\)\$|\1 $file|" '1s/$/   name/' 'w' 'q' | ed -s "$file"
done
```

---

The above code needs to adjust the space manually with the `name` column at the last field. This one needs a temp file like what @Ed_Morton did and `column` command.

```
tmp=$(mktemp)

for file in *.txt; do
ed -s "$file" <<-EOF
   H
   2,\$s|^\(.\{1,\}\)\$|\1 $file|
   1s/\$/ name/
   w $tmp
   ,d
   0r !column -t $tmp
   w
   Q
EOF
done
```

---

Caveat:
`ed` will read the whole file into memory.

Tested on 14 million rows from the OP's sample data and all is good but more than that an error. (YMMV)

```
?
Memory  exhausted
```

---

Thanks to *@EdMorton* for pointing out the memory issues.

Answer (score 0):

A `sed` solution

suggested data file contents:

```
SNP BP B   SE   P  
123 12 0.1 0.01 0.1
```

make a couple of copies with different file names

```sh
ls  
file1.dat  file2.dat 

cat file*
SNP BP B   SE   P
123 12 0.1 0.01 0.1
SNP BP B   SE   P
123 12 0.1 0.01 0.1
```

loop over the files in the dir;
`xargs` or `parallel` could replace the `for`
to finish sooner but use more resources if you have them to spare.

```sh
for f in *.dat ; do 
    sed -i "s/\(^SNP.*\)/\1\tname/;s/\(^[0-9].*\)/\1\t$f/g" "$f";
done
```

the files should now have the appended additional column

```sh
 cat file*
SNP BP B   SE   P   name
123 12 0.1 0.01 0.1 file1.dat
SNP BP B   SE   P   name
123 12 0.1 0.01 0.1 file2.dat
```

Comment: That wont work because it contains a syntax error (`/)` instead of `\)`) and the `$f` in the replacement section is inside single quotes but even if you fix that it would fail if the input file name contained various characters, e.g. `&`, `\<any number>`, `/`, `"`, and probably others I'm forgetting.

Comment: well sure ; except it does.  Thanks for pointing out  my slash backslash mixup  -- fixed now.  I can sleep just fine with folks who choose interesting filenames seeing their stuff blow up.

Comment: You're welcome. It still won't work for the other reasons I stated, though (clearly you don't believe me so maybe give it a try and notice that where you want `file1.dat` added you will literally get `"$f"` instead). Also, most people don't get to choose their interesting file names, they just get stuck having to deal with them. Those file names exist, we all run into them from time to time, and it's not hard to write code that works with them just fine.

Comment: yep.  I did a very poor job of  making the posed text be what what did run. single to double quotes should be fixed now as well. Thanks again for being my personal linter and I do mean that in the best possible way.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed and parallel):

```
parallel sed -i \''s/$/\t{}/'\' {} ::: *.txt
```

This will tag each line of each file with the name of that file whilst processing each file in parallel.

To add a header line, use:

```
parallel sed -i \''1s/$/\tname/;1!s/$/\t{}/'\' {} ::: *.txt
```

N.B. When using parallel the use of surrounding `'...'` but `\''...'\'` to avoid characters that have special meaning in shell.